# JPA native queries: hack for column and table names as variables at runtime

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I understand it's not possible to dynamically modify table names and column names in a JPA query. They have to be hard-coded.

However, I have a schema that has lots of different tables all with the same structure for the first three columns. Rather than having to write a class or a method for querying each of these I wonder if there's a quick hack for modifying the table name and column names using variables? My existing query looks like:

```
public interface ExampleRepository extends JpaRepository<Example, Long>,
    JpaSpecificationExecutor<Example> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT name_ln FROM ?1 WHERE ?2 = ?3",
        nativeQuery = true)
    String getName(String tableLookUp, String idColumn, long namespaceRefId);
}
```

This doesn't work, with MySQL producing the following error due to quotes around the table and column names:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''table_name' WHERE 'column_id' = 211833' at line 1
```

Comment: You cannot use variables like that... he JDBC api doesn't allow it.

Comment: You should use JPQL or another query syntax instead of SQL.

Comment: Yep, I know. But wondered if there might be a quick hack to avoid a more laboured approach given it's only the quotation marks around the table and column names causing the issue here.

Comment: Did you find the answer @D2J2

Answer (score 1):

You can try Param annotation for the pass value into the queries.

For example:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT name_ln FROM :tableName WHERE :columnName = :value", nativeQuery = true)
String getName(@Param("tableName") String tableLookUp, @Param("columnName")  String idColumn, @Param("value") long namespaceRefId);
```

Make sure the query result will be a single record. This may cause an error.

Comment: you can indeed use @Param("parameterName") to pass variables into queries. However, your example doesn't work. JPA won't be able to resolve :tableName and throws an exception at runtime